# FFMPEG: Loop multiple videos indefinitely

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming, rtmp, flv

I've got an interesting setup. I have four videos which are all identical in duration, identical frame rate, and have identical PTS timestamps. I wish to stream these four videos to an RTMP server but keep them synchronized so that someone switching between the streams will not jump forward or back in time, but instead pick up right where they left off.

Here's the command I'm currently using:

```
ffmpeg \
    -re -stream_loop -1 -fflags +genpts -i 01.mp4 \
    -re -stream_loop -1 -fflags +genpts -i 02.mp4 \
    -re -stream_loop -1 -fflags +genpts -i 03.mp4 \
    -re -stream_loop -1 -fflags +genpts -i 04.mp4 \
    -map 0:v -map 0:a \
        -c:a speex -ar 16000 -ac 1 \
        -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast \
        -b:v 500k -b:a 32k \
        -f flv rtmp://output/01 \
    -map 1:v -map 1:a \
        -c:a speex -ar 16000 -ac 1 \
        -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast \
        -b:v 500k -b:a 32k \
        -f flv rtmp://output/02 \
    -map 2:v -map 2:a \
        -c:a speex -ar 16000 -ac 1 \
        -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast \
        -b:v 500k -b:a 32k \
        -f flv rtmp://output/03 \
    -map 3:v -map 3:a \
        -c:a speex -ar 16000 -ac 1 \
        -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast \
        -b:v 500k -b:a 32k \
        -f flv rtmp://output/04
```

This command properly synchronizes the streams and broadcasts all four, however the moment the video ends so does the stream. Due to the `-stream_loop -1` I would expect the video to keep looping indefinitely. This is the output to `stdout` when the stream dies:

```
[flv @ 0x2392d40] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0x2392d40] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
[flv @ 0x229b980] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0x229b980] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
[flv @ 0x22f3bc0] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0x22f3bc0] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
[flv @ 0x23a4240] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0x23a4240] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
[libx264 @ 0x25ebd00] frame I:236   Avg QP:29.17  size: 20892
[libx264 @ 0x25ebd00] frame P:5412  Avg QP:32.33  size:  1892
[libx264 @ 0x25ebd00] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x25ebd00] mb P  I16..4:  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 18.5%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:81.3%
[libx264 @ 0x25ebd00] final ratefactor: 31.62
[libx264 @ 0x25ebd00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 68.8% 62.8% 34.6% inter: 8.8% 1.8% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x25ebd00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 38% 25% 19% 18%
[libx264 @ 0x25ebd00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 40% 22% 27% 11%
[libx264 @ 0x25ebd00] kb/s:515.11
[libspeex @ 0x2537580] 1 frames left in the queue on closing
[libx264 @ 0x2531d00] frame I:236   Avg QP:31.85  size: 15843
[libx264 @ 0x2531d00] frame P:5412  Avg QP:34.95  size:  2086
[libx264 @ 0x2531d00] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2531d00] mb P  I16..4:  2.8%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 37.8%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:59.4%
[libx264 @ 0x2531d00] final ratefactor: 32.38
[libx264 @ 0x2531d00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 48.4% 40.8% 13.5% inter: 12.1% 4.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2531d00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 41% 21% 26% 13%
[libx264 @ 0x2531d00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 48% 20% 24%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x2531d00] kb/s:510.33
[libspeex @ 0x2533080] 1 frames left in the queue on closing
[libx264 @ 0x22da600] frame I:236   Avg QP:26.11  size: 13705
[libx264 @ 0x22da600] frame P:5412  Avg QP:29.17  size:  2185
[libx264 @ 0x22da600] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x22da600] mb P  I16..4:  4.5%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 35.2%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:60.3%
[libx264 @ 0x22da600] final ratefactor: 28.44
[libx264 @ 0x22da600] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 37.1% 40.1% 10.4% inter: 12.3% 6.2% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x22da600] i16 v,h,dc,p: 40% 21% 22% 17%
[libx264 @ 0x22da600] i8c dc,h,v,p: 43% 18% 28% 11%
[libx264 @ 0x22da600] kb/s:511.43
[libspeex @ 0x22db080] 1 frames left in the queue on closing
[libx264 @ 0x22d7a00] frame I:236   Avg QP:30.31  size: 13811
[libx264 @ 0x22d7a00] frame P:5412  Avg QP:33.28  size:  2209
[libx264 @ 0x22d7a00] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x22d7a00] mb P  I16..4:  5.4%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 37.4%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:57.2%
[libx264 @ 0x22d7a00] final ratefactor: 31.52
[libx264 @ 0x22d7a00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 37.9% 36.7% 9.5% inter: 11.4% 5.0% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x22d7a00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 41% 23% 21% 16%
[libx264 @ 0x22d7a00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 45% 19% 27%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x22d7a00] kb/s:516.78
[libspeex @ 0x22d8d80] 1 frames left in the queue on closing
```

My FFMPEG version:

```
$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version N-90065-g8a8d0b3 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 20160609
configuration: --prefix=/home/sbarnett/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/sbarnett/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/sbarnett/ffmpeg_build/lib --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --bindir=/home/sbarnett/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libspeex --enable-nonfree
libavutil      56.  7.101 / 56.  7.101
libavcodec     58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
libavformat    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
libavdevice    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
libavfilter     7. 12.100 /  7. 12.100
libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
```

How do I get the video to loop indefinitely? Why is `-stream_loop -1` not working?

### Update (Edited with new error)

Following @Gyan's advice, I attempted to use `filter_complex` with the movie filter, however I may be doing it incorrectly:

```
ffmpeg \
    -stream_loop -1 \
    -re -i 01.mp4 \
    -re -i 02.mp4 \
    -re -i 03.mp4 \
    -re -i 04.mp4 \
    -filter_complex \
        "movie=01.mp4:loop=0[v1];[v1]setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[v1];
         amovie=01.mp4:loop=0[a1];[a1]asetpts=N/SR/TB[a1];
         movie=02.mp4:loop=0[v2];[v2]setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[v2];
         amovie=02.mp4:loop=0[a2];[a2]asetpts=N/SR/TB[a2];
         movie=03.mp4:loop=0[v3];[v3]setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[v3];
         amovie=03.mp4:loop=0[a3];[a3]asetpts=N/SR/TB[a3];
         movie=04.mp4:loop=0[v4];[v4]setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[v4];
         amovie=04.mp4:loop=0[a4];[a4]asetpts=N/SR/TB[a4]" \
    -map "[v1]" -map "[a1]" \
        -c:a speex -ar 16000 -ac 1 \
        -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast \
        -b:v 500k -b:a 32k \
        -f flv rtmp://output/01 \
    -map "[v2]" -map "[a2]" \
        -c:a speex -ar 16000 -ac 1 \
        -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast \
        -b:v 500k -b:a 32k \
        -f flv rtmp://output/02 \
    -map "[v3]" -map "[a3]" \
        -c:a speex -ar 16000 -ac 1 \
        -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast \
        -b:v 500k -b:a 32k \
        -f flv rtmp://output/03 \
    -map "[v4]" -map "[a4]" \
        -c:a speex -ar 16000 -ac 1 \
        -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast \
        -b:v 500k -b:a 32k \
        -f flv rtmp://output/04
```

This threw the following error:

```
[libspeex @ 0x23f4d80] nb_samples (325) != frame_size (320) (avcodec_encode_audio2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stream_loop isn't yet implemented for [multiple inputs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7043); you'll have to use the movie filter.

```
ffmpeg \
    -filter_complex \
        "movie=01.mp4:loop=0,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB,realtime[v1];
         amovie=01.mp4:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB,arealtime[a1];
         movie=02.mp4:loop=0,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB,realtime[v2];
         amovie=02.mp4:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB,arealtime[a2];
         movie=03.mp4:loop=0,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB,realtime[v3];
         amovie=03.mp4:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB,arealtime[a3];
         movie=04.mp4:loop=0,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB,realtime[v4];
         amovie=04.mp4:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB,arealtime[a4]" \
    -map "[v1]" -map "[a1]" \
        -c:a speex -ar 16000 -ac 1 \
        -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast \
        -b:v 500k -b:a 32k \
        -f flv rtmp://output/01 \
    -map "[v2]" -map "[a2]" \
        -c:a speex -ar 16000 -ac 1 \
        -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast \
        -b:v 500k -b:a 32k \
        -f flv rtmp://output/02 \
    -map "[v3]" -map "[a3]" \
        -c:a speex -ar 16000 -ac 1 \
        -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast \
        -b:v 500k -b:a 32k \
        -f flv rtmp://output/03 \
    -map "[v4]" -map "[a4]" \
        -c:a speex -ar 16000 -ac 1 \
        -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast \
        -b:v 500k -b:a 32k \
        -f flv rtmp://output/04
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction. Unfortunately the movie filter gave an error, as well (this one more meaningful): `[Parsed_movie_0 @ 0x27b5240] Loop with several streams is currently unsupported [AVFilterGraph @ 0x27b5140] Error initializing filter 'movie' with args '01.mp4:s=dv+da:loop=0' Error initializing complex filters. Not yet implemented in FFmpeg, patches welcome`

Comment: Changed to separate source filters

Comment: I'm getting a different error now. It may just be that I'm using the `filter_complex` parameter incorrectly. I'll update my question with my new command

Comment: Full command added. You may have to switch to single quotes for the map args.

Comment: Just as you updated your post I had figured out this much (I was googling around and found how to properly use map with filter_complex) -- however there's yet another error :( `nb_samples (325) != frame-size (320)` -- it's a libspeex error so I may be able to just switch to aac or something to work around it

Comment: Switching to aac did fix the latest issue, and I've now got a stream playing (waiting 5 minutes to see if it loops when I hit the end of the video) -- although there's a new issue, which I'll likely make a new question for. The frame rate is all kinds of jacked up.

Comment: **It looped!**. I'll make a new question for the new issue